# Monitoring ground mA current via voltage transformer

Tags: ground, current-measurement, mains, leakage-current

#### The TL;DR

Can a voltage transformer act as a milliamp current sensor? They resemble in structure.

#### Explanation

I want to build an approximate ground leak milli-ammeter (0.1-30 mA) for some appliance.

Since it's about safety

##### Requirements:

1. Allow minimum of 30 mA at all times, for the residual current breaker.
2. Should never burn out and cut off, even in the event of a full short to ground (that rules out a 1 Ω-1 kΩ resistor and a millivolt meter).
3. Should not assume that the general residual current breaker will save it before it burns (as residual CB's are electromechanical. They may be faulty).

##### Idea

Conventional CT's are not an option because they can't sense 0.1 mA. So I thought of using a voltage transformer as a wound primary CT by passing the ground through the primary:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frt65q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the normal case, I(primary) * N = I(secondary) - so we have x50 current gain. RL reflects `N*RL` on the primary

```
N * RL = 50 * 20 ohm = 1 kohm
```

Negligible to the leakage equivalent resistance and can allow

```
230 V / 1 kohm = 230 mA >> 30 mA
```

In a full short - at the secondary we have about 5 V => 0.25 A

Can this work in practice?

Comment: Since this is about safety, does your transformer allow for low enough impedance to be safe when a fault happens and live is shorted to earth? How many tens of amps will flow?  Is the applicance even earthed so why would earth wire go in the appliance?

Comment: Voltage transformers and current transformers are both transformers

Comment: Yes, @Justme. The impedence should be 1k on the primary circuit. 230v / 1k is about 230mA. About 10x the trigger current for the residual cb.

Comment: Yep, @user253751, from what I read, they are similar in their structure: 2 coils around a core. Here, since I wanna amplify (100 uA with several A tolerance) I need the same mechanism. Didn't find the catch. It freels wrong but I can't find where, if at all.

Comment: @Meymann You can't have 1 kohm in series with the safety earth if it is supposed to be the safety earth at the device behind your transformer, and it won't be with the transformer in series.

Comment: _”Conventional CT's are not an option because they can't sense 0.1 mA”_ There is nothing intrinsic preventing you from winding one which allows you to sense it. It may not be commercially available off the shelf though.

Comment: Your transformer will add a leakage path which the RCD may (should?) see as a fault.

Comment: @winny, nope. They are designed to do the opposite. I(primary)=I(secondary)/N. Unfortunately I undressed why. Think of a wire that carries 1mA while 1cm away are wires that carry 15A. Lots of noise

Comment: That’s a completely separate issue.

Comment: @PeterBennett unless I don't understand: I don't see the leakage path. The ground is passed through the transformer. It can only add some equivalent resistance. I don't see a leak path.

Comment: @winny, the thing is that I read about "wound current transformers" which are exactly for the case of low amperage. They are based on the primary wrapped around the core (rather than passing through the core), as well as the secondary. So, I thought: hey, it reminds me of something! A "regular" voltage transformer

Comment: Concept is very similar. It’s not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish but you can use a one or a few turns with thick wire on the primary if you need pass substantial fault current and clamp your secondary to some sensible voltage level easy to detect up to 30 mA and clamped/out of range after that.

Comment: Thanks, @winny , The thing is that I wanna detect less than 1mA. Think of an oven or a washing machine. I wanna monitor the much lower leaks and see what causes them before they get worse and become a real 30mA problem that will blow out my power supply (and risk lives, because... after all it's 30mA through a touchable appliance's body).

Comment: It’s been a few years since I made an appliance like that, but I recall some maximum voltage drop test for ground faults at 25 A continuous and some max allowed temperature rise when I put a choke on the ground for EMI. I don’t see any reason why you could not. Calculate how low secondary voltage you can accept, how many turns you can get by with and choose a core size accordingly. Urms=4.44fNAB.

Answer (score 1):

You must **not** do this as your transformer primary is not going to have sufficiently low impedance to support the fault flows necessary to allow prompt triggering of fault protection devices such as fuses or MCBs.

Look up the spec for the overload/fault protection device you are using, and you will find it probably needs a fault circuit impedance (L-E) well less than an ohm.

You will also find many countries have standards requiring the "touch voltage" on L-E short is less than 50V (or RCDs are used).  You transformer is going to fail that test.

And this is all assuming leakage will go down the earth wire, where it might take other routes (hence the use of balanced L-N transformers in RCDs).

If you have a mA monitor, just route the earth wire through the coil X10 and divide the reported figure by 10.

Comment: First, the impedence is enough (1k is more than enough to allow 30mA). Second, it's ground. Currents are low. That was the problem, to begin with. Third, I want to measure the leak of that specific device. The leak to its body, as this is where the main danger is

Comment: Oh, also if LE are shorted via the body (where it's most dangerous), the leak resistor above is 0. Thus, we get a simple circuit via the transformer. It will drive 230v, hence about 5v via the secondary. That is what I wrote above

Comment: You've explicitly said not to assume the RCD will work. During a L-E short this will leave the equipment metalwork at 230V.

Comment: If this is just for testing, understood, but it would not meet spec for release in a product, where to pass equipment safety test you'd need to show very low L-E impedance.

Comment: No! @colintd, the other way round: Requirement 1: don't disturb the RCB. Requirement 3: Don't build anything that may heat or tolerate a short for limited time, assuming the RCB will come to save it. I don't want a fire because the RCB is stuck (Murphy's law)